# How read files txt into project folder android

Tags: java, android, file, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

i try to create a project that can it to read txt files but show it the next error:

> /data/user/0/com.example.asojac.probandobuffer/files/hola.txt: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

The file is in the "assets" folder

My method is this:

```
public String getTexto() {
        try {
            File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() +"/hola.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "ISO-8859-1"));
            String str, str2="";

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                str2 += "\n" + str;
            }
            in.close();
            return str2;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG Exception" , e.getMessage());
        }
        return ":(";
    }
```

In the androidmanifest.xml

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I also tried whit:

```
File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir() + "/hola.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Use AssetManager to access file from assets folder `AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("hola.txt");`

Comment: Assets aren't files.  They're in your APK, and you access them via the AssetManager API

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 InputStream is;
 is = context.getAssets().open("hola.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that directory exists:

```
File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir().getPath());
fileDir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "hola.txt");
```